# How to make tables with same size regardless of the content of each table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an issue with the tables' sizes since they are not equal with the rest of the tables.

When I **click on the Cyprus selection**, the last tables are smaller than the others because of their content. I would like to expand them at the same size with the other tables above
http://www.onestopbrokers.com/regulatorszone/

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding `display: table` as a CSS property to your table.